# Remake gxp class

Tags: openlayers-2, layers

I want to remake `gxp.editFeature` class. In standart class to edit object need to choose it on map.  I want choose abject in list of objects and edit it.
So To do this i need make a new `gxp.editFeature` class. Actualy i have to remake only `this.selectControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature()` and add `select()` method in this class. And there my questions:
1 How to add objects from list to select? I use WMS so `getFeaturesByAttribute()`will work?
2 How to do that selectControl can see my layer?

Comment: D'you want to extend OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature() class?

Comment: Now i see that `gxp.featureManager` create WFS layer, so `getFeaturesByAttribute()` gonna works. This solved my questions. But i have another. If i have a list with objects and buttons for each object how to send something about chosen object to gxp?

Comment: Do this `var ffff = featureManager.featureLayer.getFeaturesByAttribute("id",'123');`
       
       `alert(ffff.length);`
       `this.selectControl.select(ffff[0]);`. Have '1' in alert but object dont select in map. What can be wrong?